# Postgres INSERT ERROR: permission denied for schema public

Tags: postgresql, sql

In Postgres I created the following table inside a db called `testing`:

```
CREATE TABLE category_google_taxonomy (
    category_id integer references category ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    google_taxonomy_id integer references google_taxonomy ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE     CASCADE
);
```

When I try to populate the table:

```
INSERT INTO category_google_taxonomy (category_id, google_taxonomy_id) VALUES
(1,7),
(2,12);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."category" x WHERE "category_id"...
                       ^
QUERY:  SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."category" x WHERE "category_id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR SHARE OF x
```

I read up a bit and eventually granted `ALL PRIVILEGES` out of exasperation, but it still doesn't work:

```
testing=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON public.category TO testing;
GRANT

testing=# \dp category_google_taxonomy
                                   Access privileges
 Schema |           Name           | Type  |    Access privileges    | Column access privileges 
--------+--------------------------+-------+-------------------------+--------------------------
 public | category_google_taxonomy | table | testing=arwdDxt/testing | 
                                           : super=arwdDxt/testing 


testing=# \dp category
                           Access privileges
 Schema |   Name   | Type  |   Access privileges    | Column access privileges 
--------+----------+-------+------------------------+--------------------------
 public | category | table | testing=arwdDxt/super | category_id:
                                                :   testing=arwx/super
(1 row)
```

On @Daniel's suggestion I tried `GRANT USAGE ON schema public TO super;`, now when I run the `INSERT` command I get:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation category
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."category" x WHERE "category_id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR SHARE OF x"
```

Here is the relevant part of `\d`:

```
public | category                               | table    | super
public | category_google_taxonomy               | table    | testing
```

Answer (score 24):

Assuming the username is `testing`, you probably want to do:

```
GRANT ALL ON schema public TO testing;
```

Note about granting `ALL PRIVILEGES`: you don't say on what this `GRANT` command was applied. Assuming it was `ON DATABASE...`, it just means `CONNECT`, `CREATE` and `TEMP` privileges, nothing about the public schema or any other contained object, which is why it "doesn't work".

**EDIT: when that's not sufficient**

If the tables referenced by the foreign keys are not owned by `testing`, their owner needs also to have the `USAGE` privilege on the schema in order to look up the referenced tables.

It's not obvious from the result of `\dp` (the result of `\d` would tell for sure) but if `category` is owned by `super` and that user also has no privilege on the schema, you'd need to assign it  with:

```
GRANT USAGE ON schema public TO super;
```

Comment: I ran the `GRANT ALL ON schema` but I am still getting the same error as before. `testing` is the correct user. I have added my original GRANT command, it was on the table, not the database as a whole.

Comment: @Rudolf: ok, I think it's because `testing` does not own the referenced tables, see my edit

Comment: thanks. I tried that and now I have a new error, which is progress. See above.

Comment: Thankyou, finally solved my problem, stuck for a day with a table that has a foreign key that is not owned by the current user

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by doing:

```
ALTER TABLE category OWNER TO testing;
```

After which the `INSERT` went smoothly. I am concerned that I may have broken other things, by changing the owner from super, but that remains to be seen.

Comment: Did anything go bad from this?

Comment: This was a few years ago, but as far as I recall nothing went wrong.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me, even in pg15

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, a user has select privilege on the parent table is good enough to insert into a child table. Do not need to be the owner of the parent table. I believe it is a bug from postgresql.